# basic manipulation of a matrix in Python and row dimension

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matrix

I read a matrix from a binary file using the following function:

```
def read_data(name,nx,ny):
    data = np.fromfile(name, count=nx*ny, dtype=np.float64).reshape((nx,ny), order='F')
    return data
```

So for instance:

```
A = read_data('myfile.xyz',10,1000)
```

In this example A is a 10 by 1000 matrix. If I look for the shape of a line of A, I get:

```
print A[0,:].shape
>>> (1000L,)
```

Now, let's say I multiply A by an 10 by 10 matrix B:

```
A = np.dot(B,A)
```

The dimension of A is still 10 by 1000 however, when looking at the shape of the first line of A I get:

```
print A[0,:].shape
>>> (1000L, 1L)
```

instead of

```
>>> (1000L,)
```

previously. Can anyone explain to me what is happening here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is your "B" is a matrix type, not a plain ndarray:

```
In [30]: a=np.random.randn(10,1000)

In [31]: b=np.random.randn(10,10)

In [32]: np.dot(b,a)[:,0].shape
Out[32]: (10,)

In [33]: np.dot(np.matrix(b),a)[:,0].shape
Out[33]: (10, 1)
```

Comment: indeed, my B matrix was built as block diagonal matrix numpy.bmat, using B = numpy.array(B) solved my problem.